# Delete a record when no corresponding record exists in first table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010

How can I delete non matching rows from a table? I have two tables that have a majority of related records. Table A must exist in table B. If table B record does not exist in table A delete table B record.

I am hoping there is a method to do this with a query rather then coding to populate a datatable and interating through each reocrd to see if there is a match.

TableA

keyID,
foreignID,
text

TableB

keyID,
recordID,
text

foriegnID and recordID are the related fields. I did not design these tables.

Somethins like this....

```
DELETE * FROM TableB WHERE (SELECT [foreignID] FROM TableA) <> recordID;
```

UPDATE: I can retireve the records needing to be deleted with query, but I would like to just delete them.

```
SELECT * FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.[foreignID] = TableB.[recordID] WHERE (((TableB.recordID) Is Null));
```

I am using vb.net to process a series of Access database.

Comment: Please show us example of the table structure, you can add some dummy data if you do not want to share information.  Your question does not contain enough clarification for anyone to answer you.  Also are you asking for a query?

Comment: access has a built-in "find dangling records" option already to do this for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DCount Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211471%28v=office.11%29.aspx) in Access SQL, and it will work regardless of whether the query is run from within an Access session or externally from VB.Net or other client code.

Start with a `SELECT` query to confirm it targets the correct `TableB` rows.

```sql
SELECT b.*
FROM TableB AS b
WHERE DCount("*", "TableA", "foreignID =" & b.recordID) = 0;
```

In human language, that `DCount` expression means *"Give me the count of TableA rows where the foreignID value matches the recordID value of the current TableB row."*  You want to identify the `TableB` rows where that count is zero.

Note I assumed numeric data types for both `foreignID` and `recordID`.  If they are text, you will have to enclose the value of `b.recordID` in quotes.

When you're ready to pull the trigger, convert to a `DELETE` query.

```sql
DELETE
FROM TableB AS b
WHERE DCount("*", "TableA", "foreignID =" & b.recordID) = 0;
```